# CLR injected .NET code crashes on File Access

Tags: c#, .net, clr, code-injection, appdomain

I injected a managed class library into an unmanaged process with the help of CLR (starting .NET 4.0.30319) [to turn a singleplayer game into multiplayer].

```
ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost;
ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo;
ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrRuntimeHost;
DWORD result;

CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, (LPVOID*)&pMetaHost);
pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo, (LPVOID*)&pRuntimeInfo);
pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID*)&pClrRuntimeHost);
pClrRuntimeHost->Start();

// execute the method "Int32 Program.Main(String arg)"
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"UnmanagedAssembly.dll", L"Program", L"Main", L"Argument", &result);
```

To call my own unmanaged methods from the target process I used the following method:

```
HRESULT ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain (
[in] LPCWSTR pwzAssemblyPath,
[in] LPCWSTR pwzTypeName, 
[in] LPCWSTR pwzMethodName,
[in] LPCWSTR pwzArgument,
[out] DWORD *pReturnValue
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms164411(v=vs.110).aspx
Which worked fine, but since it only takes strings as arguments I tried to do the same with this method, which seems way more handier:

```
HRESULT ExecuteInAppDomain(
[in] DWORD AppDomainId, 
[in] FExecuteInDomainCallback pCallback, 
[in] void* cookie
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms164410(v=vs.110).aspx
I use the same AppDomain the first method uses, my .NET callbacks are called and the cookie argument is transmitted fine.
However, if I try to get access to a file in the managed callbacks started by ExecuteInAppDomain, f.e.

```
File.Create("wat.txt");
```

The process straightout crashes with no exceptions. I didn't have that problem using the "ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain"-Method. Debugging the crash dump gives me the following information:

```
>   KERNELBASE.dll!_RaiseException@16()
[Transition from managed to native] 
mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, System.IO.FileShare dwShareMode, Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, System.IO.FileMode dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, System.IntPtr hTemplateFile)
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.Init(string path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access = ReadWrite, int rights, bool useRights = false, System.IO.FileShare share, int bufferSize = 4096, System.IO.FileOptions options, Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, string msgPath = "wat.txt", bool bFromProxy, bool useLongPath, bool checkHost)
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, int bufferSize)
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.File.Create(string path)


  Error module name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Error module version: 6.3.9600.18202
  Exception code:   e0434352
  Exception offset: 00015b68
```

Nothing on the internet helps with this KernelBase-error but it seems it's only the symptom anyway. Are there some permissions missing?
I am kinda helpless what to do. Apparently "ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain" does something differently than "ExecuteInAppDomain" although I call the same AppDomain with both methods which is the default AppDomain with unrestricted permissions.

Moreover, if I use pinvoke

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr fopen(String filename, String mode);
```

to read/write files in my managed code, it's working just fine.

EDIT:

What's working:

```
Managed Code:
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"D:/UnmanagedLib.dll", L"Unmanaged.Program", L"Main", L"Argument", &result);

Unmanaged Code:
namespace Unmanaged
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string message)
        {
            File.Create("D:\\test.txt");
            AnotherClass.CreateFile();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class AnotherClass
    {
        public static void CreateFile()
        {
            File.Create("D:\\test2.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Managed Code:
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"D:/UnmanagedLib.dll", L"Unmanaged.Program", L"Main", L"Argument", &result);
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInAppDomain(1, (ExecuteInAppDomainCallback)result, (void*)1234);

Unmanaged Code:
namespace Unmanaged
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public delegate void Callback(int arg);

        public static int Main(string message)
        {
            return Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((Callback)MyCallback).ToInt32();
        }

        public static void MyCallback(int argument)
        {
            File.Create("D:\\test.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

What's not working:

```
Managed Code:
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"D:/UnmanagedLib.dll", L"Unmanaged.Program", L"Main", L"Argument", &result);
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInAppDomain(1, (ExecuteInAppDomainCallback)result, (void*)1234);

Unmanaged Code:
namespace Unmanaged
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public delegate void Callback(int arg);

        public static int Main(string message)
        {
            return Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((Callback)MyCallback).ToInt32();
        }

        public static void MyCallback(int argument)
        {
            AnotherClass.CreateFile();
        }
    }

    public static class AnotherClass
    {
        public static void CreateFile()
        {
            File.Create("D:\\test.txt"); // crashes here
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Managed Code:
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"D:/UnmanagedLib.dll", L"Unmanaged.Program", L"Main", L"Argument", &result);
pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInAppDomain(1, (ExecuteInAppDomainCallback)result, (void*)1234);

Unmanaged Code:
namespace Unmanaged
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public delegate void Callback(int arg);

        public static int Main(string message)
        {
            return Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((Callback)AnotherClass.MyCallback).ToInt32();
        }
    }

    public static class AnotherClass
    {
        public static void MyCallback(int argument)
        {
            File.Create("D:\\test.txt"); // crashes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shodown The exception code you got doesn't help.. see [here](http://ig2600.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/why-do-i-keep-getting-exception-code.html?m=1). Can you debug it? (maybe with windbg)

Comment: "System.NotSupportedException: FileStream tried to open a device, which is no file. If you need support for devices, f.e. "com1" or "lpt1:", call CreateFile, before using the FileStream-Constructors, which handle a OS operating system handle as IntPtr." Whatever this means. The file was even created and how is "D:\\test.txt" a device. D: is one of my partitions.

Comment: (Translated from German: "FileStream sollte ein Gerät öffnen, das keine Datei ist. Wenn Sie Unterstützung für Geräte benötigen, z.B. "com1" oder "lpt1:", rufen Sie CreateFile auf, bevor Sie die FileStream-Konstruktoren verwenden, die ein OS Betriebssystemhandle als IntPtr behandeln.)

Comment: I just created a managed ConsoleApplication which starts the CLR and .NET the same way to call a new unmanaged library just for testing purposes. This new unmanaged library had no problems creating files. Tried to do the same with with the unmanaged library for the game, starting it via this ConsoleApplication and it still crashes.

Comment: The first call I do is with "ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain". In that callback I get the FunctionPointers by "Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate" for the callbacks I want to use with "ExecuteInAppDomain". Now, if the other callbacks are in the same class as my first callback, it's working. If they're from a different class, it's crashing.